# Como separar en diferentes clases cada menu?

Tags: java, clase

Lo que intento es descomponer en diferentes clases los menús para no confundirme en  una sola clase en mi caso cree 3 menus (archivo,configuracion, cambiarcolor). De esos quiero poner en cada clase. Es posible hacer eso?

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class menu extends JFrame {

public void menuarchivo(){
    //Menu archivo
    JMenuItem nuevo=new JMenuItem("Nuevo");
    JMenuItem abrir=new JMenuItem("Abrir");
    JMenuItem salir=new JMenuItem("Salir");
    //menu configuracion
    JMenuItem item1=new JMenuItem("Item 1");
    JMenuItem acercade =new JMenuItem("Acerca");
    //submenu
    JMenuItem ta1 =new JMenuItem("ta1");

    //Menu Cambiar color
    JMenuItem rojo =new JMenuItem("Rojo");
    JMenuItem verde =new JMenuItem("Verde");
    JMenuItem azul =new JMenuItem("Azul");

    //Archivo
    JMenu archivomenu =new JMenu("Archivo");
    archivomenu.add(nuevo);      
    archivomenu.add(abrir);
    archivomenu.add(salir);

    //configuracion con submenu
    JMenu confmenu =new JMenu("Configuracion");
    JMenu submenu =new JMenu("submenu");

    confmenu.add(item1);
    confmenu.add(acercade);
    submenu.add(ta1);

    //cambiar color
    JMenu ayudamenu=new JMenu("Cambiar color");
    ayudamenu.add(rojo);
    ayudamenu.add(azul);
    ayudamenu.add(verde);


    JMenuBar barramenu=new JMenuBar();
    barramenu.add(archivomenu);
    barramenu.add(confmenu);
    confmenu.add(submenu);
    barramenu.add(ayudamenu);
    setJMenuBar(barramenu);

    //Ventana Frame
    JFrame ventana =new JFrame();
    ventana.setJMenuBar(barramenu);
    ventana.setSize(500, 500);
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.setVisible(true);

    //Panel
    JPanel pa =new JPanel();
    ventana.add(pa);
    pa.setBackground(Color.red);
    JLabel nom =new JLabel("Hola");
    pa.add(nom);


    //Menus cambiando color
    //verde
        verde.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pa.setBackground(Color.green);
        }    
        });
        //ROJO
        rojo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pa.setBackground(Color.red);
        }    
        });
        //AZUL
        azul.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color celeste = new Color(10, 165, 207); // Color white
            pa.setBackground(celeste);
        }    
        });     
}

}
```

Lo explico mas detalles por si acaso clase 1 va el archivo, clase 2 va configuración y clase 3 cambiar color por supuesto llevando su menu, submenu , subitems. Bueno lo que intento es como llamo la instancia de la ventana para poder ejecutar

Por cierto en la clase ejecuccion tengo asi por si acaso

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu me=new menu();
    me.menuarchivo();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear una clase que extienda de JMENU:

```
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MenuConfiguracion extends JMenu {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MenuConfiguracion(String nombre) {
        super(nombre);
        JMenuItem item1=new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        JMenuItem acercade =new JMenuItem("Acerca");
        this.add(item1);
        this.add(acercade);
    }
}
```

Dentro del constructor de esta clase le agregas lo Items y todo lo necesario para que dentro de tu clase principal la agregues a la barra de la siguiente forma:

```
barramenu.add(new MenuConfiguracion("Configuracion"));
```

Haces lo mismo con las demás clases.